# AsyncTask and setAdapter in onCreate methods

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sdk-2.1, android-gridview

I am doing some heavy network tasks - downloading pictures (previews) -
For my main UI to not be blocked it did that in an AsyncTask, I want to put them in a GridView but I set the adapter before the AsyncTask finishes. Some code will be more helpfull

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.gridview);
            new LoadAllPictures().execute();
            GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}
```

So at the end the Logcat shows that everything had been dowloaded but nothing on my screen.
I tried doing the setAdapter part in my AsyncTask but it tells me that: `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

What should I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AsyncTask` has a useful method you can implement named `onPostExecute()`. It's called from the original UI thread after the task has completed. You can use it to set the adapter from the correct thread.

Answer (score 4):

AsyncTask has 3 basic methods:

```
protected void onPreExecute()
{
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)   
{
  // displaying images
  // set adapter for listview with downloaded items
}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
{
     // downloading and time consuming task 
}
```

so you can write `g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));` inside the `onPostExecute(Void unused)` method because at this time, the pictures are already downloaded inside the `doInBackground()` method.